# Using Compass in PHPStorm 7

Tags: phpstorm, compass-sass

So i'm using brand new PHPStorm 7, which is supposed to have full Compass support, with syntax highlighting and stuff.

I successfully install compass to my project directory, PHPStorm offers me to use `compass sass` watcher, automatically finds compass.bat and my config.rb .

And then, nothing happens - my `@import "compass"` still triggers `unable to resolve import` from watcher, i don't get any code completion or search features. The only solution i know was an old trick of adding compass stylesheets directory as a resource root to my project.

So what i'm asking - is this the way it's supposed to be, or am i doing anything wrong, because i don't think manually importing a library into every project is a proper way for supposed library support.

Comment: *"or am i doing anything wrong"* -- As far as I'm aware -- Yes. This blog post should have it all described, have a look: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/10/phpstorm-7-web-toolkit-series-stylus-and-compass-support

Comment: I'm doing everything exactly as this post says, and still no result. Unless i manually specify compass stylesheets folder as a resource root i have an error saying that an import cannot be resolved.

Comment: Well .. at the moment I can only suggest trying to quickly set up brand new project (one or two files is enough) and see if it will work there (*sometimes* it happens (for whatever reason) that old projects do not configure new functionality properly when run in newer IDE version). Other than that -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all, there is an issue on Windows.
There's the solution, and it works. Thanks LazyOne.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9139

Comment: The issue also exists for Mac OS X Mavericks